# Detect if Python is running in a Conda environment

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda

Is it possible to detect whether Python is running in a Conda environment?

I would prefer solutions that don't rely on running shell commands in a subprocess, but if that's the only option then so be it. I would assume there is something simple like an environment variable that is set inside the environment, but this kind of thing is hard to search for (and Conda documentation is not great).

Comment: Why are you asking this? Why is an Anaconda version of python more special than, say, a version installed by HomeBrew on macOS rather than the macOS native version? Or a version of python the user installed into their home directory via some mechanism other than Anaconda?

Comment: @KurtisRader I'm automating some things on a server at work that depended on Conda, and it happened to be easier in Python than in Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing, it looks like you can detect Conda usage with the `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` and `CONDA_PREFIX` environment variables. These only appear to be set when a Conda environment is active.

I will try to get an "official" answer from the Conda team and update.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
import sys, os
is_conda = os.path.exists(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'conda-meta'))
```

Comment: Do you know if this method is stable across versions? Or is this more of a hack?

Comment: you mean conda versions?

Comment: Yes. (ignore this part - I need 10 more characters)

Comment: I haven't tested it on different versions. Only in mine. For 3.5.2, it worked. I read somewhere that joining paths with history directory like this, **is_conda = os.path.exists(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'conda-meta', 'history'))** works better though.

Comment: @shadowtalker did you test this one out?

Comment: This works, but I found some environment variables that also seem to work, which also is portable to other programming languages.